# Python negative lookahead doesn't work and includes the value in the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a column in a DataFrame, a list of strings basically. I need to match and extract merchant names in it depending on where they are in the string. Then I'm returning several different columns based on various pattern searches and finally adding them together to get a comprehensive final column. Most of my patterns are working with the exception of a negative lookahead. I'm trying the same pattern as the positive but changing the `(?=x)` to `(?!x)`.  I can maybe figure out harder ways of doing it but want to keep it simple as possible.

I have to use Python's `re` module, for technical reasons. I cannot use the `regex` module.

I am trying to pull out merchant names using the `re` module.  I'm using a positive lookahead to pull out names that ARE followed by *des* using '^(\D+\s)(?=des)'.  This is working perfectly and excludes beginning with *des*.

```
def merchants(description):
  match = re.search(r'^(\D+\s)(?!des)', description, re.I)
     if match:          
         return match.group().title()    
   return None
```

As an example:

```
PLANET FIT DES CLUB FEES 10 2124301022 INDN.  returns   'Planet Fit'
SO CAL GAS DES PAID SCGC 10 1849100202 INDN   returns   'So Cal Gas'
```

NEGATIVE LOOKAHEAD:
However, when trying to get names or text from a string NOT followed by *des* using `^(\D+\s)(?!des)`

I get the following:

```
CHASE CREDIT CRD DES AUTOPAY 10 0000000002  returns   `Chase Credit Crd Des Autopay`
```

It is getting me the required results on lines without `des` but why is it including lines with `des`? Essentially, it's including the same strings as the former positive lookahead, and it's even returning the lookahead value `des` as well.

I want 2 lists that basically complement each other with no intersection so I can add them together.

Comment: That's because `CHASE CREDIT CRD DES AUTOPAY` isn't followed by `des`. It contains it, but it isn't followed by it. Do you want such a line to not match at all, or do you want it to match but terminate before `des`?

Comment: Try `^(?!.*des)(\D+\s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the negative lookahead `(?!des)` asserts not `des` directly to the right from the *current position*.

What you could do is assert not the word `des` from the start of the string, preceded by optional non digits. Note that you can omit the capture group if you want a match only.

You can make use of word boundaries `\b` to prevent an partial word match.

Using `\D` also matches `\s`, so in this case these should be at least a single whitespace char following:

```
^(?!\D*\bdes\b)\D+\s
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8fz6Jt/1)

Or if the line should not container `des` at all:

```
^(?!.*\bdes\b)\D+\s
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TH1NEs/1)

Comment: This worked and I appreciate the explanation.